# Read `Set-Cookie` headers from webrequest and send cookie details in powershell

Tags: powershell, cookies

I'm using only powershell.

I have an url to make login first: `https://.../login` with credentials

```
[string]$url = "http://blabla";
[string]$login = "$url/login";
[string]$user = "admin";
[string]$pass = "tester";
[string]$qs = "username=$user&password=$pass";

Invoke-WebRequest $login -Method Post -Body $qs -UseBasicParsing -SessionVariable session;
```

And I got some answer from server like:

```
Content-Length: 3 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 
Set-Cookie:  SID=....; path=/
```

From invoking that request, I want to get cookie `SID`, and use it in future calls:

```
Invoke-WebRequest $test -Method GET -UseBasicParsing -WebSession $session;
```

But I got 403 error.

How to pass that cookie for `$test` request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to manually pull the `Set-Cookie` header off a request, you need to capture that from your response:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest $login ...
$response.Headers['Set-Cookie'] | ? { $_ -match '^SID' }
```

But I'd like to point out you're already capturing your cookies when you use the `SessionVariable` parameter:

```
$session.Cookies.GetCookies($url)
```

You can pass these cookies to new requests by doing:

```
Invoke-WebRequest ... -WebSession $session
```

Comment: and how to pass to next request that cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

If `$test` contains that output and is an object with those properties, then you can use the following. This will output `SID=...`.

```
($test.Set-Cookie -split ";")[0]
```

If you only want the value of `SID`, then you can use:

```
($test.Set-Cookie -split ";" -split "SID=")[1]
```